# linked list, adding object im correct sorted position

Tags: java, linked-list

i am creating a linked list. I have most of the class done just cant figure out some of the parts.

I tried different codes but i don't know what the correct one is and how to do it.

Can anyone please help me.

```
public class LinkedList<T> implements LinkedListADT<T> {

    private int count; // the current number of elements in the list
    private LinearNode<T> list; // pointer to the first element
    private LinearNode<T> last; // pointer to the last element

    /*
     * Create an empty list first
     */
    public LinkedList() {
        this.count = 0;
        this.last = null;
        this.list = null;
    }

    // 1. add to end of list
    public void add(T element) {
        LinearNode<T> node = new LinearNode<T>(element);

        if (size() == 0) {
            this.last = node; // This is the last and the
            this.list = node; // first node
            this.count++;
        } // end if
        else if (!(contains(element))) {
            last.setNext(node); // add node to the end of the list
            last = node; // now make this the new last node.
            count++;
        } // end if
    }
}
```

**how to add an object in correct sorted position in the list. This is what i have but can't figure out the correct code.**

```
 /*
 * 2. add in correct sorted position
 */
    public void addSorted(T element) {
    LinearNode<T> node = new LinearNode<T>(element);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.*; public class LinkedListDemo {    public static void main(String args[]) {       // create a linked list       LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();       // add elements to the linked list       ll.add("F");       ll.add("B");       ll.add("D");       ll.add("E");       ll.add("C");       ll.addLast("Z");       ll.addFirst("A");       ll.add(1, "A2");       System.out.println("Original contents of ll:       // remove elements from the linked list       ll.remove("F");       ll.remove(2);       System.out.println("Contents of ll after de        + ll);       // remove first and last elements       ll.removeFirst();       ll.removeLast();       System.out.println("ll after deleting first a        + ll);       // get and set a value       Object val = ll.get(2);       ll.set(2, (String) val + " Changed");       System.out.println("ll after change: " + ll); 
   } }

output:

Original contents of ll: [A, A2, F, B, D, E, C, Z] Contents of ll after deletion: [A, A2, D, E, C, Z ll after deleting first and last: [A2, D, E, C] ll after change: [A2, D, E Changed, C]

Comment: I've seen this way but its not what i am doing and doesn't work on this

Answer (score 0):

You first traverse the list until you get to the spot it should be entered into then you save that node and the node before it into variables and add it there.

Note: it will get added differently based on whether it is the first, last, or a middle node so make sure you have selection statements to check for that.

Comment: what do you mean by taverse ?

Comment: go through the list and test at each point to see whether it is the correct position for the node to be inserted (usually by using a lopp and checking if whatever variable is being used to sort them is less than the node that comes after the current node. once you get to the correct position it will automatically stop the loop and as long as youve been using variable to hold the position of the current and previous nodes you can insert the node at that position)